# Python - How to create a word frequency counter with multiple files & update their key-value pairs during execution

Tags: python-3.x

I have multiple python program files on which I want to implement a word frequency counter.
Here's a brief idea about my code:

I have 2 files:

1. **main.py**, where I'm opening multiple files and calling my class & methods.
2. **SourceCodePreprocessing.py** from package **SoftPlag**, where the code is written for the processing of the input files.

### main.py

```
from SoftPlag import *
import os
inputdir = "/path/to/input/directory"
outputdir = "/path/to/output/directory"
filelist = os.listdir(inputdir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 for i in filelist:
    with open(os.path.join(inputdir + i), 'r') as f:
        fin = f.read()
        proc = Preprocessor()
        final_string = proc.scpp(fin)
        with open(os.path.join(outputdir + i + ".out"), 'w') as file_output:
            file_output = open(os.path.join(outputdir + i + ".out"), 'w')
            file_output.write(final_string)
```

---

### SourceCodePreprocessing.py

```
import re
import keyword
import os
from collections import Counter

inputdir = "/path/to/input/directory"
outputdir = "/path/to/output/directory"

filelist = os.listdir(inputdir)

class Preprocessor:
    def scpp(self, fin):
        for i in filelist:
            # remove special characters from string and convert to lower-case
            char_string = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z._]', ' ', fin).lower()

            # remove single occurrences of characters
            final_string = re.sub(r'(?:^| )\w(?:$| )', '', char_string).strip()

            if i.endswith(".py"):
                reservedwords={}  # empty list to store the reserved keywords
                reservedwords = keyword.kwlist  # reserved keywords assigned to reservedWords list

            for word in reservedwords:            # checking if reserved keyword exists in string or not
                if word in final_string:
                    # substitute reserved keywords with no spaces
                    final_string = re.sub(r' \b' + word + r'\b', '', final_string)

                else:
                    continue

        words = final_string.split()
        counter = Counter(words)
        print(counter)
        key = counter.keys()
        value = counter.values()
        print(key)
        print(value)

        return final_string
```

Here's what I'm trying to achieve in **SourceCodePreprocessing.py** file:

1. Implement word frequency counter on file 1 and store the output key-value pair.
2. Implement word frequency counter on file 2 and store the key-value pair in a temporary variable.
3. Merge the temporary variable with the key-value pair of file 1, apply word frequency counter on this new dataset and store the updated key-value pair in a final variable.

The final outcome will be the key-value pair of file 1 along with the updated key-value pairs of the remaining input files.

The above steps should continue till the key-value pairs of all the input files have been generated. Key-value pairs should be stored in discrete variables depending upon the number of input files.

Currently, I'm able to generate keys & values for all the input files but I'm unable to devise a logic for my requirement mentioned above.

**Help will be highly appreciated!**

Answer (score 1):

Yo!
First off, in python, when referencing a global variable/object, you need to use the "global" keyword, otherwise you're creating a new instance of the variable locally.

In response to the comment you made about your function (which seems to be the crux of your code) the proper code would be:

```
keylist = {}
def word_counter(self, final_string):
    global keylist # THIS is the line you're missing
    for i in filelist:
        words = final_string.split()
        counter = Counter(words)
        key = counter.keys()
        value = counter.values()
    keylist = key
    print(keylist)
```